# Check if cookies are enabled in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi

Can a desktop app check this using some `Win API` functions or via `Windows Registry`? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  IOmNavigator::cookieEnabled to check whether persistent client cookies are enabled. You can get an IOmNavigator * from IHTMLWindow2::get_Navigator. And if you don't have an IHTMLWindow2 available you can CoCreateInstance a CLSID_HTMLWindow2.